# Slf4j/log4j: FileAppender added at runtime doesn't work

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I am using log4j 2.5 and slf4j 1.7.19. This is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">D:/opt/verzeichnis-shop/logs/</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <Console name="A1" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5p][%15.15t]%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-6r ..%35.35c:%-4L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>


        <RollingFile name="A2" fileName="${log-path}/vzshop.log" filePattern="${log-path}/vzshop_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5p][%15.15t]%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-6r ..%35.35c:%-4L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="de.mycompany.vzshop" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="A2"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="A2"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

I am initialising it like this:

```
LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
File file = new File("path/to/log4j2.xml");
context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

Now I want to add a FileAppender at runtime:

```
public static void appendBookLogger(String bookDir, String uuid) {

    LoggerContext loggerContext = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    String path = bookDir + File.separator + uuid + ".log";
    logger.info("Adding appender: " + path);

    final Configuration config = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
    PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout("[%-5p][%15.15t]%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-6r ..%35.35c:%-4L - %m%n", null, config, null,
        null,false, false, null, null);
    Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender(path, "false", "false", "File", "true",
        "false", "false", "4000", layout, null, "false", null, config);
    appender.start();

    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getRootLogger();
    rootLogger.addAppender(appender);
    logger.info("Appender added.");
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The log file (path) is being created but remains empty. I would expect to contain the last log statement ("Appender added.") though.
I don't get any error messages at all.

Do you know what could be the problem here?

Comment: pretty sure the rootlogger will not have the appender-ref objects it needs.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was giving the root logger the appender by calling `rootLogger.addAppender(appender);`?

Comment: I just realized that the log file doen't remain empty since we included MongoDB in our application. In fact, one MongoDB log statement gets written into the file, e.g.:
`[INFO ][ost-startStop-2]15:56:12,454 52234  ..      org.mongodb.driver.connection:71   - Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:68}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.` Now I am totally confused. What does that mean?